# How do I add UTM sources to RSS links?

Tags: feeds, google-analytics

I want to add UTM sources to RSS links. I have already tried to change the link display and modify the URL, but so far I am unable to see any sort of tracking in Google Analytics.

Comment: Your RSS feed page won't have any JavaScript on it, so UTM variables won't be passed to analytics. Feedburner can be used as an alternative - your on-page RSS link points to Feedburner's URL for your feed and Feedburner will then track stats for you.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong: what is feed burner? how does it work? any tutorial please?

Comment: It's a service owned by Google which gives you options for syndicating feeds. You need a google account. But there may be better alternatives. Hopefully someone else will suggest some.

Comment: Looks like it's dying - this page has some up to date alternatives. http://www.feedburner-alternatives.com/

Comment: thanks but do they offer integration with google analytics, i  mean the alternates?

Comment: No idea, sorry.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me exactly what do you want to do?  add UTM to feeds link to see how many time people click on that link etc?
I can't understand what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

my first question is what are you trying to track.

you say

> add UTM sources to RSS links

I'll assume you want to track those clicks to your rss feed.

theres a way to do this without pushing your feed to external places

your changing the link display is nearly there but you will want to put a click event track to fire a google analytics event

this is a good [reference](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?topic=11014):

you could take it one step further and add '[autotrack](https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack)'  which does a whole bunch of good things for you including declarative event tracking, so rather than the above, you use [declarative attributes](https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack/blob/master/docs/plugins/event-tracker.md) in your html

*this will only track clicks on the link.* as it relies on the users browser loading and executing the javascript.

If you wanted to ensure tracking every request to that feed you have another option that doesn't rely on external services (other than google analytics).
you could use the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) in google analytics that lets you post any type of event from any system.

you could then create a module and implement either hook_init, or hook_exit to make a call to the measurement protocol end point logging the request of the feed in your google analytics account

Comment: thanks for the reply tim, but isnt the purpose of RSS feeds to generate a code from server side? i mean some 1 else may have my RSS URI, and its upto them whether they wanna use my RSS feeds or not, and its also upto them if they wanna use it with JS plugin or not, and if have taken your answer incorrectly please correct me and guide me.

Comment: no, thats fair. It depends on what you're after - yes RSS is a syndication format, and your response helps. I wonder if my response is to the wrong question ! based on my assumption that you want to track requests to your rss feed, you'll then want to look at the second part of my answer - that would track everyone that requests your rss feed. another other option is to look at your web server logs. or are you after tracking people clicking links within your RSS feed.

Answer (score 1):

The question does not specify if this is for Drupal 8 or Drupal 7. So I will go ahead and share what I just implemented in Drupal 8 and should work closely in Drupal 7.

Basically I had to preprocess the Views RSS row and append my UTM information to the link. Here is how I am tagging taxonomy term feeds with an explicit check to see if it is my Drupal Planet feed.

```
function bootstrap_glamanate_preprocess_views_view_row_rss(&$variables) {
  /** @var \Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view */
  $view = $variables['view'];
  if ($view->id() == 'taxonomy_term') {
    $term = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($view->args[0]);
    $label = $term->label();
    if ($label == 'drupal') {
      $source = 'Drupal Planet';
    }
    else {
      $source = 'Term Feed';
    }
    $variables['link'] .= '?utm_source=' . $source . '&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=' . $term->label();
  }
}
```